# What is the IP address of the Facebook server that sends me app deauthorization callbacks?

Tags: facebook, ip, whitelist

I would like to whitelist the IP addresses of the Facebook servers that sends me a callback whenever a user deauthorizes my App. Which IP addresses should I whitelist?

Answer (score 4):

You can check Facebook's IPs with:

```
whois -h whois.radb.net "!gAS32934"
```

Documented at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity/

Answer (score 0):

Many people have asked, but Facebook does not publish their IP addresses, and they change over time from what I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find it easier to use domain rather than ip.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, Facebook, Inc. owns the following subnets:

31.13.24.0/21
31.13.64.0/19
31.13.69.0/24
31.13.72.0/24
31.13.73.0/24
31.13.75.0/24
31.13.76.0/24
31.13.77.0/24
66.220.144.0/21
66.220.152.0/21
69.63.176.0/21
69.63.176.0/24
69.63.184.0/21
69.171.224.0/20
69.171.239.0/24
69.171.240.0/20
69.171.255.0/24
74.119.76.0/22
103.4.96.0/22
173.252.64.0/19
173.252.70.0/24
204.15.20.0/22

Comment: You have any reference for this information? But the real problem is that this list could change anytime and break the app. (Deauthorization callback are pretty important for user privacy and rights)

Answer (score 0):

You really should use DNS when ever possible.  The correct "host name" will generally get you where you expect to be regardless of what IP is being used today.

Answer (score 0):

To find the current list of IPs use:

whois -h whois.radb.net -- '-i origin AS32934' | grep ^route