# Facebook Like Not Posting to Wall

Tags: html, facebook

I am trying to get the Facebook Like button to post to the wall but it will not. i'm unsure why as I copied + pasted the code provided by the Facebook site. When I check the Network panel in the inspector I see that a 200-OK connection was made to Facebook. When I go to my Facebook wall, I do not see that post. When I try liking things from other sites, I see it gets posted on my wall immediately.

`<div class="fb-like services" data-href="http://www.my-url.com/" data-send="false" data-show-faces="false" data-layout="button_count"></div>`

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<meta property="og:title" content="My Site" />
<meta property="og:type" content="game" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.my-url.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="My Site" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="100002412494318" />
```

Comment: Did you scroll down the page where you got that code and notice that there is actually a second step in implementing the like plugin?

Comment: @Lix There are only two steps I believe. The first one is to write the JS, and the second is the HTML. I have included both of these in my question above.

Comment: `"Step 2 - Get Open Graph Tags"`. Scroll down a bit more ;) You'll have to include some meta data on your page to let Facebook know what title, images and descriptions to use in the "like post".

Comment: @Lix Silly me, let me give that a shot.

Comment: @Lix I tried but still no luck.

Comment: Could you possibly post a link to the page?

Comment: @Lix Sorry, its on my local. I will modify my post to include the `meta` tags I used.

Comment: Ah HA! ;) Hehe sorry... **This** is the problem, @icu... In order for Facebook to create a "like post", Facebook's servers have to be able to access the URL that the user is liking. You should leave debugging this till the page is publicly available so that Facebook's servers will be able to see it.

Comment: Oo, I see. Great, thank you for clarifying. Can you post your reply as a response so I can set it as the answer?

Comment: wow... that accept was fast :P Thanks! I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was stated in the comments to the OP, there are two issues here that might be causing problems with your like plugin.

Firstly one must take care to implement some `og:meta` tags on the URL that you are wanting to place a like button. These meta tags help Facebook to decide what title, description and image to use in the story that is posted on the users wall/timeline.

The second thing that you need to take care of is that your URL needs to be accessible by Facebook's crawlers - only that way can Facebook create a feed story pointing to your URL. As you have stated [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14965870/facebook-like-not-posting-to-wall#comment21012016_14965870), the URL you are debugging is located on your local machine so Facebook's servers have no access to it. Facebook will not post a like story to an inaccessible URL (what would be the point in that?).

In order to make sure you like button is operating correctly, you'll need to wait till your URL is accessible by Facebook's servers. If you upload your site to a "real" live server, you'll still be able to limit access to this URL with passwords and ip restrictions. In such a case, you could possibly [include Facebook's servers IP addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535553/what-is-the-ip-address-of-the-facebook-server-that-sends-me-app-deauthorization) to your whitelist or use some other method (perhaps examining the user agent) to allow Facebook access to your URL and it's `og:meta` tags.

Facebook has supplied us with a great took to debug these kinds of issues. This tool is aptly named the **[Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)**. It will examine the URL you provide, list the data it retrieves and display exactly how Facebook sees your site. It will also alert you to any missing data and suggest steps to correct these problems.